# Why objectMapper fails if I put a method different to set and get property in Java?

Tags: java, json, string, object, jackson

I have a class named Car that represents an entity, it has a property that let me knows if the car has the doors opened or not.

```
private int doorsOpened;
public void setDoorsOpened( val ) { this.doorsOpened = val; }
public int getDoorsOpened() { return this.doorsOpened; }
```

When I need to know that, I simply call:

```
if (car.getDoorsOpened() != 0) {
    car.startAlarm();
}
else {
    car.allIsFine();
}
```

But, I don't want to use `getDoorsOpened() != 0` comparison, for that reason I created a new method named `doorsOpened()` that brings to me the boolean value:

```
public boolean doorsOpened() { return this.doorsOpened != 0; }
```

But with this new method when I want to do this:

```
String carData = objectMapper.writeValueAsString( car );
```

I get this exception:

```
Unhandled server exception: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.desafioguerreros.artifacts.car.entities.Car["volunteer"])
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.desafioguerreros.artifacts.car.entities.Car["volunteer"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:232)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:197)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:187)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:647)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:114)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2866)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2323)
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, seeing the stacktrace, it looks like one of the attributes in the entity is null and it is causing the exception. If my understanding is correct, if you have a non-conventional getter, Jackson will just ignore the field and not throw any exception. If you want to have a custom getter and include that field in serialization, you can use `@JsonProperty` as shown below.

```
public class car{
    private int doorsOpened;

    @JsonProperty(value="doorsOpened")
    public boolean doorsOpened(){
        return this.doorsOpened != 0; 
    }

}
```